# What is the simplest possible configuration of Apache2 mod_proxy?

Tags: apache-2.2

I have an apache2 running and i have a service available as http://www.domain.com:8080/sitename

What will be a simplest apache2 configuration so entering "http://www.domain.com" in browser will show "http://www.domain.com:8080/sitename"? I have added:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPass / http://www.domain.com:8080/sitename/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://www.domain.com:8080/sitename/
</VirtualHost>
```

But, of course, this is not workig. Is it some simple configuration i can use for such redirect or i'm doomed to copy-paste a 100+ line configs from tutorials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are almost there try adding

```
ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    allow from all
 </Proxy>
 ProxyPreserveHost On
```

to your VirtualHost  definition

Comment: 1) Default: ProxyRequests Off 2)your answer is no different from my

Comment: @alvosu: 1. Better to be safe than sorry with some things. 2. That happens a lot here - you'll get used to it.

Answer (score 4):

My working config(ubuntu 10.04):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPass / http://www.domain.com:8080/sitename/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://www.domain.com:8080/sitename/
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  <proxy>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </proxy>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks. Using this and adding mod_proxy_http solves the problem

Answer (score 2):

That looks good. Check your error log. Do you have both mod_proxy and mod_proxy_http loaded? You should also have "ProxyRequests Off" to prevent you from becoming a forward proxy

Comment: Default: ProxyRequests Off

Answer (score 0):

The <proxy> statement is for a 'forward' proxy, which allows requests for any url on the web.

Loading mod_proxy_http and using 'ProxyPass' and 'ProxyPassReverse' statements will do what you want.

[Apache 2.2 mod_proxy documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) for more.

(yes this is a bit of a duplicate answer, but I'm trying to make things clearer and hoping nobody inadvertently starts an open proxy)